# Jar renamed as .txt: Will it load?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader, executable

Suppose I have a jar which is renamed to .txt, will the classloader be still able to load a class from it?
This question is in context with a customer who has kept a backup within the classpath but with .txt extension. Will it have an impact? Since it is a prod server, it takes time to remove it and test.

Comment: If you change it back to `jar` it will

Answer (score 2):

If the txt file is part of the classpath then Java should have no problems accessing the jar, but I don't recommend it! It's a lot less hassle if you keep jars as jar extension or copy to other directories.

So if your customer has made a copy of the file with ".txt" but kept the original jar as-is the application would run fine as long as classpath is unchanged.

But if your customer renames the jar as txt and does not update classpath to match the new weird filename, then the classes would not be found - same issue if your app scans that dir for ".jar" files it would not find as it would miss out the renamed jar.

For example this quick test I made with `javap` works on a class copy.Copy in copy.jar

```
> javap --class-path copy.jar copy.Copy
public class copy.Copy {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.io.IOException;
}

> mv copy.jar test.txt

> javap --class-path test.txt copy.Copy
public class copy.Copy {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.io.IOException;
}
```

Running also fine:

```
> java --class-path test.txt copy.Copy
Usage: copy.Copy [-options] {fromdir} {todir}
```

Comment: The problem is the customer has both .txt and .jar. 
The .txt is a previous revision which he keeps as backup.

Our host is tomcat and hence it runs as a webapp. 

Now what if the classpath is like 

<libdirectory>/*

In this case it will look for all types? So when it looks up will it get two versions of the same class?

Thats the problem we are trying to figure out.

Comment: I think many startup scripts for launching webapp servers would have some type of classpath autoscan using `libdirectory/*.jar`, but you'd be very unlucky to find that your startup was scanning for `libdirectory/*` instead - as often people would leave other files like README there too and they would also be included. Let's hope that is the case - at least your client didn't copy as xyz-old.jar to confuse matters further!